# Branch vent in cold ventilated attic space

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

We have added a garage with a bedroom and bathroom above it. The bathroom obviously requires ventilation, so I am planning a branch vent from the main stack. The branch will run through the ventilated attic, and we are in a cold climate (Quebec, Canada). I have a few options:

1. Branch a 3" pipe from the main 4" stack and run it above the insulation, entirely in the cold attic space. I will be able to run the whole branch with a 1/4"/foot slope.
2. Branch a 3" pipe from the main 4" stack and run it in the insulation. It would be neither in the cold attic space, nor the warm interior space but buried half way through the fiberglass batts. I would not be able to run the pipe with a slope.
3. Same as #2 but with a 1.5" or 2" pipe.
4. Forget the branch vent and install an air admittance valve at the end of the bathroom drain

As I understand it, #4 would be possible as long as there is a vent stack that vents outside *somewhere* in the house. This would be the case.

What would you guys do?

Comment: Option 5. Short & direct secondary vent through the roof right there.

Comment: @Ecnerwal that is certainly an option. The roof was done just last week, so I'd like to avoid making a new hole and calling the roofers back. What do you think of the other options in comparison to your suggestion?

Comment: I would second option 5.  It is just a vent pipe, but a cold horizontal/low slope pipe could freeze condensation/moisture and cause problems.  Adding a vent though a new roof should be easier/less problem causing than an older roof.   #4 air admittance valves seem to have have shorter life spans, requiring replacement more often than vents.

Comment: You haven't specified the length this needs to go. Most codes require slope on vents, so non-sloped would be a violation. Your assertion that you "cannot" slope inside the insulation is opposite my knowledge of doing that, but if the run length is absurd it may be difficult. Freezing up a vent is all too possible with a long horizontal cold run, while verticals are easier to keep open. I regard AAVs/mechanical vents as an option of last resort, since they are prone to failing and stinking, requiring replacement, but probably no more so than a long horizontal vent in January/February in Quebec.